Configuring docker build spring native for project, error 1: ./mvnw: not found
I'm building a project into spring boot native, but I'm having a problem when running ./mvnw.
-- docker file:
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.8.4

RUN curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share \
    && ln -s /usr/share/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

WORKDIR /app

COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app/api.jar

RUN chmod +x mvnw

RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests=true && \
    ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/api.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=prod,api-docs"]

Build log:
Deploying '\<unknown\> Dockerfile: Dockerfile'…

Building image…

Preparing build context archive…

\[==================================================\>\]951/951 files

Done

Sending build context to Docker daemon…

\[==================================================\>\] 112.3MB

Done

Step 1/13 : FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11

latest: Pulling from adoptopenjdk/openjdk11

17d0386c2fff: Already exists

c0ad5eae1b2c: Already exists

5191baf664db: Already exists

Digest: sha256:a33af2d09aa350cba11ad445dc275869d148dfe5667b4a4fe1f6d99f0d3e0247

Status: Downloaded newer image for adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest

\---\> 7167a74d4185

Step 2/13 : ARG TIMEZONE="Asia/Saigon"

\---\> Running in 1d8c0980b66c

Removing intermediate container 1d8c0980b66c

\---\> 1ffca3fde83b

Step 3/13 : ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven

\---\> Running in f08f78028908

Removing intermediate container f08f78028908

\---\> 55e027c13b28

Step 4/13 : ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.8.4

\---\> Running in 27a078115683

Removing intermediate container 27a078115683

\---\> 74b0819e286b

Step 5/13 : RUN curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/$%7BMAVEN_VERSION%7D/binaries/apache-maven-$%7BMAVEN_VERSION%7D-bin.tar.gz     && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share     && ln -s /usr/share/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

\---\> Running in f6709de5e9c7

Removing intermediate container f6709de5e9c7

\---\> 76b7785afbcd

Step 6/13 : WORKDIR /app

\---\> Running in 91d569a7ac53

Removing intermediate container 91d569a7ac53

\---\> 59e6b6e64f07

Step 7/13 : COPY mvnw .

\---\> f970067d3bdd

Step 8/13 : COPY .mvn .mvn

\---\> 70c8321d91b6

Step 9/13 : ARG JAR_FILE=target/\*.jar

\---\> Running in 9d0fd1904919

Removing intermediate container 9d0fd1904919

\---\> 9d8dab80ab85

Step 10/13 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app/api.jar

\---\> 9f22facf6046

Step 11/13 : RUN chmod +x mvnw

\---\> Running in 29a835802114

Removing intermediate container 29a835802114

\---\> 10ba8e663158

Step 12/13 : RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests=true &&     ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image

\---\> Running in 33c296796b88

/bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found

Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c ./mvnw package -DskipTests=true &&     ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image' returned a non-zero code: 127

Failed to deploy '\<unknown\> Dockerfile: Dockerfile': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream

I tried configuring mvnw settings first but it still doesn't seem to solve the problem.

You're downloading all of maven. Just use mvn, not copy and use mvnw... It's also not clear why you're trying to copy and run jar files from the host. Aren't you trying to get maven to create those within the container?
